# C++ Depth First Search of Trie with prefix parameter

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, trie

I'm trying to implement a trie that can print out the frequency of words with a given prefix.

Edit: Thanks to @kaidul-islam finding my error with the following error:

```
new_word->child[letter]->prefixes_++;
```

Below is the fixed code:

Trie Class:

```
class Trie
{
public:
    Trie(): prefixes_(0), is_leaf_(false), frequency_(0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            child[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    virtual ~Trie();

    //Child nodes of characters from a-z
    Trie *child[26];
    //vector<Trie> child;

    int prefixes_;

    //accessor & mutator functions
    bool GetIsLeaf() { return is_leaf_; }
    void SetIsLeaf(bool val) { is_leaf_ = val; }
    int GetFrequency() { return frequency_; }
    void SetFrequency(int val) { frequency_ = val; }
    int GetPrefixes() { return prefixes_; }
    void SetPrefixes(int val) { prefixes_ = val; }
    bool is_leaf_;

private:
    //bool is_leaf_;
    int frequency_;
};
```

Function in Question:

```
void AddWord(string &word, Trie *root)
{
    Trie *new_word = root;
    new_word->prefixes_++;
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        int letter = (int)word[i] - (int)'a';   //extract character of word
        if(new_word->child[letter] == nullptr)
        {
            new_word->child[letter] = new Trie;
        }

        /*cout << "not value of x: " << new_word->child[letter]->GetPrefixes() << endl;
        int x = (new_word->child[letter]->GetPrefixes())+1;
        cout << "value of x: " << x << endl;
        new_word->child[letter]->SetPrefixes(x);*/
        new_word->child[letter]->prefixes_++;

        new_word = new_word->child[letter];
    }
    new_word->SetFrequency(new_word->GetFrequency()+1);
    /*
    cout << "Word: " << word << endl;
    cout << "frequency: " << new_word->GetFrequency() << endl;
    cout << "prefixes: " << new_word->GetPrefixes() << endl;
    cout << "is leaf: " << new_word->GetIsLeaf() << endl << endl;
    */
}
```

Comment: Make sure the constructor initializes all pointers with nullptr. Step with a debugger and look at the contents of all the pointers. You reference without checking, and one of them is probably not initialized...

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: When i was debugging, this was the error @JacoboCórdova:


    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick inspection, I found you didn't initialize member variables in your constructor.

```
Trie(): prefixes_(0),
        is_leaf_(false),
        frequency_(0) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        child[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Unlike global variable, there is no guarantee that `prefixes_` will be 0 by default on declaration. And `child[i]` is not guaranteed to be `nullptr` too. You need to initialize everything.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot something so small. Now i just need to get the search function working. @kaidul-islam do you think I should make a copy constructor since there is pointers in each class?

Comment: Yes, if you need to make this class a bit pattern oriented, you should define a copy constructor according the rules of three https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)